# How to format queryStore svelte urql 2.0<?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, urql

I'm attempting to make a mutation/query store request to a faunaDB database. I'm not sure how to format the query to prevent the error

```js
import { mutationStore, gql } from "@urql/svelte";
import client from "../client.js";

const loginMutation = gql`
   mutation ($email: String!, $password: String!) {
      login(email: $email, password: $password) {
         secret
         ttl
      }
   }
`;

let login = mutationStore(client, loginMutation, {
    email: "shadid12@email.com",
    password: "123456"
});

console.log(login);
```

Error:

> Invalid AST Node: [function query].
> Error: Invalid AST Node: [function query].

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```html
<script>
import { mutationStore, gql } from "@urql/svelte";
import client from "../client.js";

const loginMutation = gql`
   mutation ($email: String!, $password: String!) {
      login(email: $email, password: $password) {
         secret
         ttl
      }
   }
`;

let login = mutationStore({
    client,
    query: loginMutation,
    variables: {
        email: "security@fauna-labs.com",
        password: "qZXUEhaNdng9"
    }
});

$: console.log($login);
</script>
```

Comment: I hope those credentials are not relevant...